# Install pg gem on CentOS 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, centos, centos6

I'm trying to setup my VPS (CentOS 6.4) with ruby on rails and postgres.

I installed ruby (2.1.0p0), rails (4.1.0), and postgresql (9.3.4) with no problem.

When I try create new rails app (rails new new_app -d postgresql) it stops when installing the pg gem. I've looked into all SO posts about this error and tried pretty much everything I could find. The most suggested was to run "yum install postgresql-devel" and still didn't work.

Below you can find the ssh output and the mkmf.log. Let me know if need more information...

---

## Output

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1120:in `block in find_header'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in checking_for'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking_for'
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1119:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:48:in `'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

---

## mkmf.log

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward -I/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I. -I/usr/include     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib -Wl,-R/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib -L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-R/usr/lib64 -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -Wl,-rpath,'/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,'/../lib' -L'/../lib' -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: Permission denied
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Before:**

*For Centos 6*: Right install Postgres 9.* with this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-centos-6).

**After:**

```
yum install postgresql-libs postgresql-devel
```

**Helpful instruction:**

[How to setup RoR with Postgres](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres)

Answer (score 7):

As you are not using the outdated PostgreSQL version that comes with CentOS 6 (PostgreSQL 8.4), you need to install the `-devel` package matching your version (PostgreSQL 9.X).

The easiest way is to use the [official PostgreSQL yum repository](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/).

As the latest version is 9.5 and it is compatible with all 9.X versions I will write the instructions for that one. In the future you can refer to the [official instructions](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/) for the updated commands.

```
yum install http://yum.postgresql.org/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql95-devel
```

Then install the gem with the `-with-pg-config` option:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 6):

This was easier for me:

```
ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pg_config /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: This is much easier then specifying in each bundle. However you must remember to update this on major postgresql version changes (9.*.*)

Comment: This won't work with PostgreSQL 9.X because CentOS 6 comes with PostgreSQL 8.4

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
before "bundle:install" do
  run "ls -l #{fetch(:latest_release)}/Gemfile"
  #run "bundle config  --local --gemfile=#{fetch(:latest_release)}/Gemfile build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config"
  run "cd #{fetch(:latest_release)} && bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config"
end
```

Comment: Where are you supposed to try that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the pg gem with the postres pg_config file path option:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config
```

Please update the path according to your system

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my mac and it was a  bash / RVM issue. I had to add this to my bash:
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm” . Given that it's finding the config file I would look into this.